# Problema con .focus, me genera un loop infinito

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Hola mi problema es que tengo un textbox, el cual me verifica por medio de un where, que lo que yo ingrese existe, si eso existe me va a llenar la información de otro textbox. Si lo que ingrese es null, (es decir el where no lo encontró) al perder el focus de mi textbox, este desplegara un mensaje de error **Cliente no encontrado**, y si encuentra dentro del where al cliente, me va a desplegar el nombre del cliente en el siguiente textbox.

El problema, es que si bien funciona y me trae el nombre del cliente al perder el focus, si es que no llega a encontrar al cliente, pasa a mi mensaje de error que es: **cliente no encontrado**, el problema acá es que me genera un loop infinito, cuando sé despliega el mensaje **cliente no encontrado** y yo pongo **aceptar**, mi idea es que el foco vuelva a mi textbox para esta vez si ingresar un dato correcto, pero al aceptar el mensaje vuelve a salir, una y otra vez, sin dejarme hacer nada más que apretar aceptar, infinitamente. Este es mi código: (mi método public void traerrazon es el método por defecto de mi textbox)

```
public void traerRazon(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
 var traer = (from cli in MainWindow.lista where cli.rut == txt_rutclia.Text select cli).FirstOrDefault();
 if (traer != null) {
  txt_raz.Text = traer.razonsocial;
 } else {
  txt_rutclia.Focus();
  MessageBox.Show("Cliente no encontrado");
 }
}
```

Comment: Cuando verifica lo que ingresaste lo hace a medida que vas escribiendo? o tienes un botón para pulsarlo una vez que escribiste? o lo haces capturando la tecla ENTER? Es importante detallar esas cosas ya que puede que estés modificando el comportamiento habitual de un evento, como TextChanged, LostFocus o algo parecido.. si produce un loop es porque hay un EVENTO gatillándose al cerrar el cuadro de diáogo, tengo la respuesta pero necesito esa información primero.

Comment: @Leodev, verifica lo que escribi una vez se pierde el foco del textbox. Que puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Tu error es porque llamas al LostFocus y luego cuando muestras el mensaje le asignas Focus de nuevo pero el mensaje se lo quita y se forma un loop, te doy 2 soluciones, aunque aclaro que llamar a Focus() directamente dentro de LostFocus() está "prohibido":

1) Llamar a Focus a través de un delgado:

Con este método y llamando al Focus a través de BeginInvoke NO se produce más el loop por LostFocus:

```
private void traerRazon(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var traer = (from cli in this.lista where cli.rut == txt_rutclia.Text select cli).FirstOrDefault();
    if (traer != null)
    {
        txt_raz.Text = traer.razonsocial;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente no encontrado");
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                txt_rutclia.Focus();
            });
    }
}
```

PERO! Cuando cierres el programa, es posible que se gatille el evento nuevamente pues se pierde el Foco y tu mensaje de "Cliente no encontrado" podría desplegarse justo antes de que el software termine.

2) Cambiar el uso de LostFocus por detección de teclas con KeyDown:

Esta es la solución que yo tomaría. Considerando que el evento se gatilla por LostFocus sería mejor usa la tecla TAB (o ENTER) para ello, es decir, al pulsar la tecla TAB (que básicamente es igual a perder el foco) o ENTER, que busque un resultado, entonces te ahorras que por cualquier cosa que hagas en la ventana se pierda el foco y se esté gatillando el mensaje sin control, lo puedes hacer con KeyDown de la siguiente manera:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var traer = (from cli in this.lista where cli.rut == txt_rutclia.Text select cli).FirstOrDefault();
        if (traer != null)
        {
            txt_raz.Text = traer.razonsocial;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente no encontrado");
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
                {
                    txt_rutclia.Focus();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Y el control quedaría así:

```
<TextBox KeyDown="OnKeyDown" x:Name="txt_rutclia" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Y ya con eso debería funcionar.

**EDIT2:**

Según lo que me indicas podrías refactorizar el código que se encarga de buscar la información, ponerlo dentro de un método aparte para poder llamarlo desde varios métodos controladores de eventos, así:

```
private void Buscar()
{
    var traer = (from cli in this.lista where cli.rut == txt_rutclia.Text select cli).FirstOrDefault();
    if (traer != null)
    {
        txt_raz.Text = traer.razonsocial;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente no encontrado");
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                txt_rutclia.Focus();
            });
    }
}
```

Entonces el método del primer `TextBox` que controla si pulsas TAB o ENTER lo tendrías que dejar así:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        Buscar();
    }
}
```

Y luego, en el segundo `TextBox` le agregas un controlador para su evento `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, que se encargará de hacer algo cuando lo clickées:

XAML:

```
<TextBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="txt_raz_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" x:Name="txt_raz" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

C#

```
private void txt_raz_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Buscar();
}
```

Y listo.

Comment: lamentablemente el loop persiste.. que puedo hacer?

Comment: Listo, he cambiado la respuesta y probado los resultados, verifica que sea una respuesta que te acomode (porque de funcionar, funcionan).

Comment: gracias por tanta dedicación, pero ha surgido un nuevo problema: el codigo en la parte "ThreadStart" me da un error (lo subraya en rojo) y dice : "El nombre o tipo de espacio de nombres 'ThreadStart' no se encontro (falta alguna directiva using o referencia de ensamblado? ayuda T-T

Comment: edito: @Leodev, el codigo me ha funcionado, me faltaba agregar un using System.Threading;. Ha funcionado la solucion 2. con tab y con enter. Pero el problema es que tambien necesito validar que el usuario clickee otro textbox. Es decir, si bien con tab y con enter funciona, no funciona al momento de cambiar con un click a otro textbox. COmo puedo añadirle a la solucion 2 que tambien al clickear otro textbox o elemento de la ventana, tambien me tire el error.

Comment: Te agregué lo que pides, aunque te toca verificarlo ya que estoy sin el compilador en este momento.

Comment: Pero que pasara si clickea en otro orden los textbox?

Comment: Se supone que el primer TextBox no detecta clicks, solo el segundo ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y a funcionado!!!!!